# AS3 Matrix transform

Tags: actionscript-3, matrix, transformation

I am not good with Matrix transform thus I need help on this. Please refer to the link below

http://img402.imageshack.us/img402/9610/sampleyn.png

Assuming the left and right red box are on the same stage, but with different shape & position.

I need to get the matrix transformation needed to transform shape2 to shape1, this includes the x & y position too.

point "a" will be map to point "a"
point "b" will be map to point "b"
point "c" will be map to point "c"
point "d" will be map to point "d"

Kindly help me out with this, as I am not sure what keywords to search for.
thanks in advance!

Comment: This thing looks like you ned a "skew" transformation. This is doable via matrices, but there is no built-in methods to make one in the class.

Comment: hi Vesper, any pointers? I'm totally clueless about matrices, that's why i have no idea how to research on it. thx

Comment: If you want to learn about transformation matrices in flash, I think this is still the best resource: http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/transformmatrix/

Comment: Hmm, this means the required transformation simply cannot be performed using only 2D matrices. Pitiful :( Then yes, try 3D matrices.

Comment: Ya, i guess it can't be done.... need to look into the 3d matrices that you've suggested. Thanks man! Thanks danii for the link too.

Answer (score 0):

Try [rotating it about the y axis](http://www.siggraph.org/education/materials/HyperGraph/modeling/mod_tran/3drota.htm) :

[image]

See the live example [here](http://megaswf.com/s/2519173).

Comment: This will make source point A into destination point B, which is not what OP wants. Also this is a 3D transformation, which is likely out of scope for him.

Comment: likely out of scope for him O.o ?? He wants to do it rite? Besides, Check your argument again... The origin lies away from the shape, in the figure...

Comment: See, when you turn that shape in 3D as you have drawn, it'll align wrong points, just take two pieces of paper and fold one over another like you do with the book pages. Under "likely out of scope" I mean that he likely does not use Stage3D and its features to produce such a transformation.

Comment: It does exactly wat I expect it to... please see the live example. http://megaswf.com/s/2519173

Comment: Well, that's not what **I** expected that turn to do, I have read your post as if you are using a book-type turn around Y axis, that is, the plane with the shape contains the axis. This way it does what's expected.

Comment: Thanks loxxy for the suggestion, but I was just looking for a 2d matrix transformation, rather than making the whole thing complicated. Any help on that? and just to clarify, the polygon is not a rectangle in perspective view, i think my example somehow mislead loxxy into thinking that it's a reflect-able plane, sorry about that.

Comment: Try this library http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/distort-movieclip-or-image-in-flash-with-as3